# Excel VBA Freezing double loop to color certain range if criteria is met

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, freeze

**Hello!**

I'm still new to VBA, but using nearly all my brain cells i managed to build the code below.
However, when i execute the macro, Excel seems to be working for ages but accomplishes nothing. I don't receive any error message, but it appears Excel is stuck in an endless loop.
I suspect there's a significant flaw in my code somewhere, but i can't seem to figure out where.

```
Sub Makro_color_cells()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim groupfrom As Range
Dim groupto As Range
Dim groupfinal As Range

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
x = 4
t = 0

Do While x < lastrow

    Set groupfrom = Cells(x - 1, "F")

    Cells(x - 1, "B").Activate
    Do While ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
       t = t + 1
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop

    x = x + t
    Set groupto = Cells(x - 1, "F")
    Set groupfinal = Range(groupfrom, groupto)

    If Not (groupfinal.Find("Storage") Is Nothing) Then
    Range("groupfinal").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    t = 0
    Set groupfrom = Nothing
    Set groupto = Nothing
    Set groupfinal = Nothing

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The purpose of the code is to color some cells in column F based on some criterias:
Column B contains numbers with duplicates placed next to each other. Consider all rows with identical values in column B as a "group".
Now if one or more rows in a "group" has the text "Storage" in column F, then all rows in that "group" should have their F column colored.

The basic idea behind my code is to locate the "group" and using `groupfrom` and `groupto` to set a range `groupfinal` equal to the group's cells in column F.
Then using the `range.find` method to test if there's an occurrence of "Storage".

I tried troubleshooting, but with no luck.
Any ideas why the code doesn't work?

I appreciate any help and I'm open to ideas with a different approach than my code.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are your first defining `t`?  You can also use `Debug.Print` to get console line output which will be easier to debug.

Comment: What is your `Do While ActiveCell...` loop trying to accomplish? There are bound to be better ways of doing it than that. You should avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` in your code - they're almost always unnecessary and just slow down processing.

Comment: @Morpheus You are right - the first defining `t` is missing. I edited the post to include it now, but the problem is still the same unfortunately.

Comment: @FreeMan I completely agree - there must be a better way of doing it than this. The idea is to have a loop inside the `Do While x < lastrow` loop that counts the number of cells in a "group" and adds that number to `x`. This counter is the variable `t`.

Comment: Two Questions: Is your data sorted into groups down the column? for example: 1,1,1,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7 or mixed down the column: 1,7,1,4,5,5,1,6,4,7,7,5. If it is sorted in to groups then this will be straight forward, if not, can the rows be sorted into groups?

Comment: @5202456 Thank you for your comment. The data is sorted into groups like your first example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all your groups will be grouped together and not mixed, then a vba script can be used to check for the group value, use the total number of that value to define the range and change the cell colours in column F:

```
Sub Makro_color_cells()

Dim LastRow
Dim CurrentRow
Dim GroupValue
Dim GroupTotal
Dim GroupCheck

GroupValue = Range("B1").Value ' get the first value to search
CurrentRow = 1 ' Define the starting row

    With ActiveSheet ' find the last used cell in the column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For x = 1 To LastRow ' start the reapat until last cell reached

        GroupTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:B" & LastRow), GroupValue) ' search for total of the group values
        GroupCheck = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F" & CurrentRow & ":F" & CurrentRow + GroupTotal - 1), "Storage") ' search for "Storage" in the range from current row to total rows of the same group values

        If GroupCheck >= 1 Then ' if the "Storage" search is equal to one or more then colour the range of cells
            Range("F" & CurrentRow & ":F" & CurrentRow & ":F" & CurrentRow + GroupTotal - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + GroupTotal ' We know how many cells are in the same group so we can bypass them and move the current row to the next group of values
        GroupValue = Range("B" & CurrentRow).Value ' Get the value for the new group

        If GroupValue = "" Then ' Check the new group value and if it is nothing then we can exit the 'For Next x'
            Exit For
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - and fast! Also very well done on explaining each line thoroughly - really helps understanding the code a lot!
Just in order for me to be certain:
Essentially instead of using a loop that counts the number of cells in a group like i did you use the CountIf function?
Thank you very much - I would upvote twice if i could ;)

Comment: Yes, countif function to determine the amount of rows that contains the same values (Group) and also then to check for "Storage". The total number of a value within the Group is used to find the next group of data, helping to speed up the process

Comment: Perfect :)
Yes using the number of identical values to find the next group is clever. I tried doing that with my second loop and using `t` as the counter, but this is a much more efficient approach.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: JoeBerg, I did have a look at you code but could not quite figure it out, that's why i wrote some new code. I always try to comment my code even if it is just for myself as no doubt if ever I comeback to it in the future it will help me out. Also I like to use descriptive names when declaring variables as again it make more sense when reading the code, as you did in your original code, but you had not declared x and t so that was confusing.  Other coders my frown upon this as it does make the code longer, but that's personal preference and may make a diffrence on a fare larger piece of code.